# The Anthropomorphized Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Another that rhymes, my author desired
'Twas limericks and riddles that he so admired
To hide a relation
*To earn reputation*
and brighten your day through wordplay inspired

A puzzle I am, though not yet begun
Of words I'll speak later, each stanza has one
Their connection concealed
Your mind you must wield
Once gathered, you'll publish my scheme and be done.

Two parts both wound tight
Near my bridge they do meet

When you fancy a bite
Eggs and bacon I heat

Of efforts in vain
My partner's delayed

Things weak under strain
Or a sweet snack homemade

With only a few emerges a pattern
Like Sega and Goya exposed my friend [Saturn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18424/surely-you-know-this-prominent-figure-hints-added)
These next few you'll find
Are of the same kind
As those layed above left for you to discern

A thing often wasted
Though not touched or seen

A thing often tasted
Or known for its green

A man builds a wall
Without wood or brick

Another might fall
If that wall is too slick

Another that rhymes, my author desired
'Twas limericks and riddles that he so admired
To puzzle and jest
And never to rest
'Til you've been enlightened, an answer acquired

**Warning:** This puzzle was written in a land where caramel has two syllables, aunt is pronounced "awnt", and words of _ittle rhyme with _iddle.

Comment: I have a possible solution, but my word for the "weak under strain" stanza is a weak fit (pardon the pun). I assume all stanzas fit cleanly, and I'm therefore wrong?

Comment: If you're unsure about your answer, it's probably wrong, especially if you have the three above it correct.

Comment: Figured as much. Only asked because everything else fit so nicely that it felt odd that one would be "off" (in the way that assonance doesn't feel quite right amongst true rhymes).

Comment: +1 for me trying to imitate this riddle but then realizing that it would take way longer than expected

Comment: Your limericks' meter overextends the long lines. They're only supposed to go for three triplets but you've made them go for four.

Comment: ... and you didn't say _anything_ about "piddle"?

Comment: @JoeZ A limerick requires a rhythm and an AABBA rhyme scheme. As far as I can see, a *traditional* limerick has three triplets, but my limericks are just as happy and healthy with four.

Comment: @randal'thor I *really* wanted to, but decided it might be too obscure. Maybe I should have used four _iddle words to solve my regional rhyming woes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is:

> **Riddle** & **Rhyme**

Based on the fact that:

> The first four (non-limerick) stanzas all give words that rhyme with "riddle" and the next four all give words that rhyme with "rhyme".

Specifically the word derived from each stanza is as follows:

*Two parts both wound tight / Near my bridge they do meet*

> **Fiddle** (from [user1618143](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20013/5208) - the taught string & body meet at the bridge of the instrument)

*When you fancy a bite / Eggs and bacon I heat*

> **Griddle**

*Of efforts in vain / My partner's delayed*

> **Little** (from the idiom "too little, too late", meaning "efforts in vain", with the "partner" of *little* being *late*, or "delayed")

*Things weak under strain / Or a sweet snack homemade*

> **Brittle** (two definitions, since brittle means weak and peanut brittle is a sweet snack)

*A thing often wasted / Though not touched or seen*

> **Time**

*A thing often tasted / Or known for its green*

> **Lime** (or arguably thyme)

*A man builds a wall / Without wood or brick*

> **Mime** ("builds" an imaginary wall to be trapped behind)

*Another might fall / If that wall is too slick*

> **Climb**(er)

Comment: You've got the final answer, but some of the words used to get there are incorrect.

Comment: +1, nice one! Now you're exactly 1 rep point behind Aggie Kidd; good to see you guys sticking together ;-)

Comment: @Roland - So middle=>fiddle has been confirmed, and you've implied that diddle is wrong. Are these the only two? Or are others incorrect too?

Comment: Those two are the only ones. Once diddle is replaced with its solution, the answer is complete.

Comment: Sorry if regional differences are ruining some stanzas. I asked some colleagues here in the Midwest, and we all think *brittle* rhymes with *riddle*. :P

Comment: @Roland - Not a problem. It's a cool liddle rittle regardless. :P The realisation that cultural quirks may be at play is why I posted anyway. I would personally put a harder T in brittle (BRITtle), but can hear the american briddle pronunciation in my head. Still stuck on the "efforts in vain" one though. I want to say "whittle", but that ignores the "partner" bit... will keep thinking.

Comment: @Roland - unless it's "tiddle"? Which apparently means to potter/fidget ("efforts in vain"), and also means seesaw, which could delay your "partner" (you go down, they go up, etc)?

Comment: HINT: The stanza references an idiom

Comment: @Roland - Ahh, ok. Think I got it now (see edit). :)

Answer (score 5):

Proposing a couple of corrections to Alconja's answer, which Roland said is not quite correct:

*Two parts both wound tight / Near my bridge they do meet*

> Fiddle. The strings and bow are both tight, and they meet at the bridge.

*Another might fall / If that wall is too slick*

> Rime.

Comment: The first is *fiddle*, but *climb* is (at least what I intended for) the last one.

Answer (score 4):

Proposing a correction to Alconja's answer, on top of user's:

*Of efforts in vain / My partner's delayed*

> Twiddle. A person accomplishing nothing is twiddling his thumbs (an English idiom).

Comment: Not quite, though as I wrote the stanza, I noted that this would also be a valid solution. The solution which I intended fits very well though: The stanza is speaking as the solution, so ponder what its partner might be...